# Expressing positive integers as $2a+4b+5c+6d$, for $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$ non-negative, with $a+c$ as small as possible

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, puzzle

Let $n$ be a positive integer where $n > 1$ and $n \neq 3$

I need a way to return all solutions of $2a + 4b + 5c + 6d = n$ where $a, b, c$, and $d$ are non-negative integers and $a + c$ is as small as possible so I can choose a random one.

This is a problem I have conceived myself but I believe it is solvable.

Comment: No, the goal is to make n by adding up either 2, 4, 5 or 6 keeping the 2s and 5s at a minimum and either the 4 or 6 at a set random number depending on the outcome of the flip. There is only one flip of the coin

Comment: This is not clear.   Take, say, $n=7$ and assume you toss $H$.  Them $m=1$, yes?  So if the random number of $6's$ turns out to be $1$ then you have to use $6$ once, which leaves you the impossible task of getting $1$ out of $2,4,5$.  Similarly if $n=10$.

Comment: I see no issue in the case of 10. If n = 10 then floor(10/6) = 1 so you have use the 6 once and the 4 once or the 2 twice (obviously 4 once) and then floor(10/4) = 2 which means you use the 4 twice and the 2 once. In the case of 7 there is an issue if the toss is heads so continue under the assumption n is not equal to 7. I will add an edit as I believe 7 to be the only case it breaks under

Comment: @Dandb79 if $m$ is choosen as the random  number all numbers of the form $6k+1$ or $6k+3(for\space  heads)$ $4k+1$ or $4k+3(for\space  tails)$ don't work

Comment: @quantus14 Yes, that is exactly correct. Thank you for raising that, I will reconsider the problem domain

Comment: @quantus14 It has now been edited. It has the same outcome for my application through a different and almost certainly solvable domain

Comment: @Dandb79: Since you've removed the coin-flipping stuff, I guess that doesn't matter. Anyway ... You can express any number as $n=2a+4b+5c$, where $c := n \operatorname{mod} 2$ and $a := (n-5c)/2 \operatorname{mod} 2$. (So, $a$ and $c$ are each either $0$ or $1$.) If it happens that $a=1$ and $b \geq 1$, then you can create a $6$; in that case, take $d=1$, and reduce $a$ and $b$ each by $1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $n$ is odd we must use 5 once because adding any number of 2's, 4's, and 6's results in an even number. In the odd cases after the subtraction of 5 we are always left with an even number. If $n$ is odd let $n_2=n-5$. If $n$ is even let $n_2=n$. We then can remove a random number of 6's ($d$). $d$ is between 0 and $\lfloor\frac{n_2}{6}\rfloor$. Let $n_3=n_2-6d$. $n_3$ must be even. If $n_3$ is of the form $4b+2$ then one 2 must be used and then the rest can be 4's. If $n_3$ is of the form $4b$ then the rest can be 4's. In conclusion $n$ can be one of four outcomes given that $d$ is randomized.

$6d+7+4b$

$6d+5+4b$

$6d+2+4b$

$6d+4b$

Comment: That is a brilliant solution. Thank you very much